# Не могу разобраться как сделать редактирование записи в базе данных

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, crud

Недавно начал знакомиться со Spring, MySQL, Hibernate и т.д. В качестве практики пытаюсь сделать CRUD приложение. Вывести таблицу на странице, добавить/удалить запись все работает. А вот с редактированием проблемы.

У класса-сущности только 2 поля: `id` и `name`.
Вот методы контроллера (первый для получения страницы редактирования конкретной записи, второй для изменения этой записи):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edition(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("entity", service.get(id));
        return "edition";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String edit(@ModelAttribute("entity") TestEntity testEntity){
        service.edit(testEntity);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Метод репозитория:

```
public void edit(TestEntity testEntity) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(testEntity);
    }
```

И тело (body) страницы редактирования:

```
<h2>${entity}</h2>
<c:url value="/edit" var="edit"/>
<form:form action="${edit}" method="POST" modelAttribute="entity">
    <label for="name">NAME</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Edit">
</form:form>
```

Т.е. я передаю на страницу редактирования атрибут `"entity"` (я специально добавил вывод на странице `${entity}`, чтоб точно видеть, что там нужная запись из БД), затем пытаюсь его изменить. Но когда жму *submit* и вызывается метод *edit* оно почему-то пытается изменить запись с `id = 0` (которой нет) и вылетает исключение:

```
Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [test1.entity.TestEntity] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [test1.entity.TestEntity#0]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [test1.entity.TestEntity] with identifier [0]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) : [test1.entity.TestEntity#0]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Никак в толк не возьму, что я делаю не так.
Версии использую Spring 5.1.1, Hibernate 5.3.7

Comment: По-моему,  редактирование это RequestMethod.PUT)

Comment: Я попробовал сейчас сделать в контроллере метод PUT (ну и на странице в форме убрал POST), пишет: "Request method 'POST' not supported". Тут же не важно, какой у нас там метод, кнопка "submit" так и так отправляет данные на сервер, делает POST запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому, что вы не передаёте параметр `id` в контроллер. Для того чтобы сервер знал, какую запись из базы данных нужно обновлять, требуется передать значение `id`.

Обычно это делается с помощью добавления невидимого поля в форму, содержащего требуемое значение.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}">
```

Comment: Да, точно, помогло )) Спасибо огромное